# How to get the file size using Javascript in Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, filesize

How can I get the size of file written in a sandboxed section of chrome using javascript ?

Comment: How was the file created? AJAX request?

Comment: Nope. It was created using the HTML5 FILESYSTEM API, with the command,windowsRequestFileSystem();

Comment: Odd...I can't find anything on it...

Answer (score 0):

It is not amazingly easy.

The FileEntry and Entry interface has a method called getMetaData, but this doesn't include the file size.  The only way that I could work out how to do it is as follows:

1. Get the file entry
2. Call file, to get a reference to the file, the file is of type Blob.
3. Read blob.size

It means potentially loading the file.